# Weird logic error for a Timer controlling a relay from a Pi (Python)

Tags: python, timer, gpio

I am using Python on a raspberry pi to control a relay for a timer for a light. The functions are fairly straightforward:

```
    def timer_check(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
        if self.timer_on <= now < self.timer_off:
            GPIO.output(self.light_pin, False) #Turn the light on
        else:
            GPIO.output(self.light_pin, True) #Turn the light off
```

self.timer_on and self.timer_off is initialized thusly:

```
        self.timer_on = datetime.time(self.thresholds['TON'],0)
        self.timer_off = datetime.time(self.thresholds['TOFF'], 0)
```

I've printed each of these and it always shows up with the correct time and time zone.

**The problem:**

I have the relay to turn on at 10am. This always works. The issue is that at 22, when the relay is to turn off. This has never functioned properly. I have tested the relay to see if it will turn on and off and it works in shorter time frames--that is, if I set on_time to 10am and off_time at 10:30am, or 10 and 11. In these tests both on and off works as intended.

However it never works right for 10 - 22. I thought maybe it gets stuck somewhere, but this isn't the case. After 22 I can restart the program and it will turn off the light. Then at 10 the next day the light will turn on as intended. But the 22 always fails.

I've checked to make sure that python supports the kind of operator I'm using. It works in every test case I've built.

I've printlined **on_time**, **off_time**, and **now** to make sure the time was in the correct time zone. Everything seems correct here.

I've checked other pins and other relays to see if it was a hardware issue. It wasn't.

I've chosen other times, such as 20, 18, and 23 to see if there was some weird issue there. Still didn't work.

I've brought the on/off times close together. This seems to make it work as expected. So I suspect that the issue is inherent to the gap in time between the on state and off state. Maybe the issue is inherent to RPi.GPIO. However if this was the case then why isn't there a problem when I reset the Pi at 22 to turn the light off and at 10 it comes on as expected?

It's not making any sense to me. I can link my github and the issue is requested. Thank you.